# Turning Specific Age Ranges Into a Series of Numbers

Tags: php

I am allowing users to store age ranges for online courses in 2 formats.

10-15

and

10+

I need to store these in the database, however, as actual numbers (up to 100).

So, for 10-15, I would store 10,11,12,13,14,15

And for 10+ I would store 10,11,12,13,14,15,16 etc. all the way to 100.

The goal is to be able to more easily filter on the database.

Looking for PHP suggestions on how convert these two number types into the series of numbers.

Here is what I have so far.  I believe I have the dash scenario handled.

```
if (preg_match_all("/[\+]/", $agerange)==1) {


}
elseif (preg_match_all("/[\-]/", $string)==1)
{
    $start = $agerange[0];
    $end = $agerange[strlen($agerange) - 1];

    array range ( $start , $end , 1 );
}
```

Comment: Show your code what you have try to done so for.

Comment: For 10-15 scenario, you can use [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function to store numbers in this range into database.

Comment: Edited to show what I have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function like this to map the range string into a set of numbers:

```
function map_range($range) {
    if (preg_match('/^(\d+)\+$/', $range, $matches)) {
        return range((int)$matches[1], 100);
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/^(\d+)-(\d+)$/', $range, $matches)) {
        return range((int)$matches[1], (int)$matches[2]);
    }
    else {
        // illegal
        return array();
    }
}
```

The function checks for legal ranges i.e. two numbers separated by a `-`, or a number followed by a `+` and uses the [`range`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function to create an array of the values specified by that range string. Ranges of the form `n+` are assumed to go from `n` to `100`.

The output of the function can be [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)'d to create a comma separated list of values e.g.

```
$ranges = array('10-15', '90+', '20-30');
foreach ($ranges as $range) {
    echo implode(',', map_range($range)) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
10,11,12,13,14,15
90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100 
20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/7Yi0N)

Comment: Just saw this @St. Nick.  Thanks much for your answer.

Comment: @CRAIG no worries, I like your take on my name... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Its is batter to store date range in one column to store in different column.

> from_age  and to_age

it is batter for query
suppose you want to insert range 10 - 15 then
from_age = 10 and to_age = 15

and 10+ from_age=10 and to_age=100

Comment: In my case, I need to store them all in one column, unfortunately.